# How to make my android device to be recognized by MacOS?

Tags: android, macos, flutter, device

I run `flutter doctor` and give me 2 issues in 2 categories. One of them (which I'm not able to install my app on my smartphone) is that my macOS does not recognize my device:

```
MacBook-Pro-de-Jesus:~ jesushedo$ flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.5, on Mac OS X 10.14.6 18G103,
    locale es-ES)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.3.1)
[!] Android Studio (version 3.5)
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[✓] VS Code (version 1.41.1)
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

How could I make my device to be recognized ?

Thanks for all.

Comment: Most probably you need to enable the Developer Options and have "Debug enabled".

Answer (score 0):

**I think its drivers problem**

1. Try to download vysor on your Mac
       [Vysor download page](https://www.vysor.io/download/)
2. Then activate your android USB debugging:

**For Android 4.2 and newer, Developer options is hidden by default; use the following steps:**

3. On the device, go to Settings > About .
4. Tap the Build number seven times to make Settings > Developer
   options available. Then enable the USB Debugging option.
5. Select Settings > Security and set Enable ADB to On.

**Tip**: You might also want to enable the Stay awake option, to prevent your Android device from sleeping while plugged into the USB port.